# Why can't I use a select table as input of from in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm new at SQL stuff and as a training, I just want to play around with stack exchange data explorer, I want know why the below code doesn't work:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM (SELECT id
      FROM Posts
      WHERE PostTypeId = 2 AND OwnerUserId = '##UserId##')
```

My main goal is finding users which their answers is more than 1000, but for know, I can't figure out what the problem of that code is, and why I didn't get the number of a user's answers ...

Comment: just add " AS foobar" ad the end of your statement and it should work. The sql statement requires you to set an Alias for the new table you created in the subquery

Comment: @Webeng tnx man, i get my answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `HAVING` to return only id's with more than 1000.

```
select id
from Posts
group by id
having count(*) > 1000
```

Perhaps you want some other aggregate function in the having clause, like `sum(points) > 1000` or similar.

Comment: tnx for responding, but i think your code shouldn't have rest part of AND, and sth else, when i run ur code on stackexchange server i got nothing, would u check your code again?

Comment: Removed the WHERE clause.

Comment: the err get fixed but again i got nothing as result

Comment: Try a lower value than 1000.

Comment: i don't think that would be the problem, cuz when i try 10 as instead of 1000, again nothing changed, i think count(*) caused that, do u get any result from that code ???

Comment: this the [link](http://data.stackexchange.com/) you could try which server u want, i try that code on stackoverflow's DB.

Comment: dear my friend, i could find the way for achieving my goal, I post the code below, thanks for helping me ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have to set an alias for your derived table:

```
select count(*)
from (SELECT id
  FROM Posts
  WHERE PostTypeId = 2 AND OwnerUserId = '##UserId##') s
```

Comment: thanks for answering, now could you tell me how can i reference to the column of 's' table ???  I want to use it at new line ....

Comment: I am not sure what you mean... `select s.id` maybe?

Comment: dear my friend, i could find the way for achieving my goal, I post the code below, thanks for helping me ;)

Answer (score 1):

by helping of my friends, I could handle my problem.the key part is SQL statement requires us to set an Alias for the new table that created in the subquery. after that we could use this alias wherever we want,this code will work for achieving my main goal:

```
select x.OwnerUserId
from (select Posts.OwnerUserId,s.cnt
      from Posts inner join (SELECT Posts.OwnerUserId, count(OwnerUserId)as cnt
                             FROM Posts
                             WHERE PostTypeId = 2
                             group by Posts.OwnerUserId) as s on Posts.OwnerUserId=s.OwnerUserId )as x
where x.cnt>100
group by x.OwnerUserId
```

If anyone could find better way which has better performance, plz share it here ;)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id, COUNT(*)
FROM Posts
WHERE PostTypeId = 2
AND
OwnerUserId = '##UserId##';